# New project missing xml files and folders

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, new-project

When creating a new project on Android Studio, some files are missing on my new project like:

*xml files:*
activity_main.xml, AndroidManifest.xml

*Folders inside res folder:*
layout, values

I dont know if theres more things missing. Im using windows 8 Pro

Comment: can you post a snap of your AS?

Answer (score 0):

The only folders you need in your res folder are probably "values" with a "strings.xml" inside. and you need a "styles.xml" in the values fodler. copy this text to your styles.xml:

```
    <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

the  tags have to go in the strings.xml file too.
google for a androidmanifast xml file and copy that to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the settings when creating the project, there should be a setting that says something like:
"Generate xml files"

just some ideas